# Value types as required fields

Tags: swashbuckle

Why does not **Swashbuckle** generate the required constraint for all the not `Nullable` value types? Anyway, is it a good idea to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indicate required properties of complex input parameter object in Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41282520/indicate-required-properties-of-complex-input-parameter-object-in-swagger-ui)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swashbuckle: Make non-nullable properties required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46576234/swashbuckle-make-non-nullable-properties-required)

Answer (score 2):

By default, **Swashbuckle** does not mark as required any fields of exposed objects.

To do so, you should just add the [RequiredAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on properties you need to be required from the Swagger definition file.

[Swagger specifications](http://swagger.io/specification/) are at start not treating any fields as required by default; from specifications on `required`:

> Determines whether this parameter is mandatory. If the parameter is in
>   "path", this property is required and its value MUST be true.
>   Otherwise, the property MAY be included and its default value is false