# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to specify required fields in Swagger Documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am implementing Swagger Documentation.

I have this code.

SwaggerDocOptions:

```
public class SwaggerDocOptions
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>()
    .Configure<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>((swagger, service) =>
    {
        foreach (ApiVersionDescription description in service.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            swagger.SwaggerDoc(description.GroupName, new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = swaggerDocOptions.Title,
                Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
                Description = swaggerDocOptions.Description,
                TermsOfService = new Uri("mysite.org/LICENSE.md"),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = swaggerDocOptions.Organization,
                    Email = swaggerDocOptions.Email
                },
                License = new OpenApiLicense
                {
                    Name = "MIT",
                    Url = new Uri("mysite.org/MyApp")
                }
            });
        }

        var security = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            {"Bearer", new string[0]}
        };

        swagger.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Scheme = "Bearer",
            BearerFormat = "JWT"
        });

        swagger.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();

        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        swagger.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

    });
// Register and Configure API versioning
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
});

// Register and configure API versioning explorer
builder.Services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
{
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;

});


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

I want the fields that are required to be specified in the Swagger Documentation. That is,

> https://localhost:44361/swagger.index.html

However, when I lauched the Application, the required fields are not specified in

> https://localhost:44361/swagger.index.html.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You can simply add `[Required]` attribute to make it mandatory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify if a field is optional or required in OpenAPI/Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113049/how-to-specify-if-a-field-is-optional-or-required-in-openapi-swagger)

Comment: @Anuraj - I already have [Required], but it's not solving the problem.

Comment: for what fields you need to specify the required, can you add that code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swashbuckle: Make non-nullable properties required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46576234/swashbuckle-make-non-nullable-properties-required)

Answer (score 0):

Add the **[Required]** attribute to the property of the class:

```
public class SwaggerDocOptions
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Organization { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And don't forget add the **[Produces("application/json")]** attribute to the API controller. Its purpose is to declare that the controller's actions support a response content type of application/json:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
```

Comment: I am not using  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, but FluentApi. I even added [Required] in the model.  Already I added [Produces("application/json")], but it's not showing required.